# How do I get curl to work with SSL endpoints?

Tags: macos, command-line, high-sierra

I continue to get the following error when trying to curl an `https://` endpoint:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "“https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I've tried manually installing with `--with-darwinssl`:

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.58.0.zip
unzip curl-7.58.0.zip
cd curl-7.58.0
./configure --with-darwinssl
make
sudo make install
```

I *think* this is installing to `/usr/bin/curl` but I've tried this one as well as what's in `/usr/local/bin/curl` and continue to get the same result. From the `-V` details, it *seems* like SSL should be enabled:

```
/usr/bin/curl -V
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

I've also tried:

```
brew uninstall --force curl
brew cleanup --force -s curl
brew prune
brew install curl --with-openssl
```

But no luck. I'm about out of ideas here, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Protocol "“https" not supported
          ^
```

See that extra quotation mark? That's a curly quote, not a normal double quote. `curl` thinks the protocol is literally called `“https`.

I bet you copy/pasted a URL from a web page which included that symbol and `curl` is trying to interpret it as part of the protocol. Remove it, and `curl` should start working as expected.

Comment: Nice catch, https should work "out of the box"